# Give an example of a closed subset of R and an open cover of that set that has no finite subcover

Tags: general-topology

My example is a tad all over the place so any input would be very helpful thank you.

Let A={[0, 1] intersection Q}, for all x belonging to A.  Now, let y belong to A and be irrational.  Then {(-1, y-1/n): n belonging to N}U(y,2) would be an open cover of A.

Comment: $[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ is unfortunately not closed. Think about $\Bbb Z$ instead.

Comment: Or try $R$ itself.

Comment: Is [0,1] intersect Q compact under R? @Nitrogen

Comment: No, compact subsets of $\Bbb R$ are closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $S = (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$. $S$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ since $\overline{S} = (-1,1)$, which is an open set.

The family of intervals

$$\{ (n-2, n+2) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

is an open cover of $S$ with no finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $\mathbb{Z}$ nad the open cover $A=\{(-n,n)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

A is an open cover of $\mathbb{Z}$  that  does not contain a finite subcover of $\mathbb{Z}$ .

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed set with respect to the euclidean topology in the real line.